# Repeat a certain value, different number of times in R

Tags: r

## **Question**

This question contains 2 parts.

**First,** I have a data frame which contains some numbers in a column. It looks something like this.

```
> df <- data.frame(sr.no.=c(1,2,3,4,5),num=c(1,0,2,1,0))
> View(df)
  sr.no.    num
  1         1         
  2         0
  3         2
  4         1
  5         0
```

Now, I wish to repeat a fixed value (say the text "x") depending upon the number in the 1st column of the data frame. If there is more than one repetition, I want them to separated by a space.

## **Desired Output**

```
> View(df)
  sr.no.    num     rep
  1         1       x
  2         0       
  3         2       x x
  4         1       x
  5         0
```

I tried using the rep function, but it gives some error and I don't fully understand how the rep function works. I think I know what it does, but not 'how'..

```
> rep("x",df$num)
Error in rep("x", df$num) : invalid 'times' argument
> rep("x",df[df$num])
Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'integer'
```

**NOTE:** The actual data frame is large, so we cannot just create a list of 'x' manually.

Now, the **second** part is unrelated to my problem above, but its got to do with the rep function only.

If i write this,

```
> rep(1:2,df$num)
Error in rep(1:2, df$num) : invalid 'times' argument
```

I get error. But if I write this,

```
> rep(1:length(df$num),df$num)
[1] 1 3 3 4
```

I get the above output. Can someone please explain to me, firstly how to solve my repetition problem; and then how come rep is giving error in one case while not in the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have said that the data set is quite large,using apply function might take time to process.
Instead , you can use the 
library(stringi)
and the function stri_dup
in which case you will get the same output but at a faster time.

so use

```
library(stringi)

cbind(df,rep=stri_dup("x ",df$num))

  sr.no. num  rep
1      1   1   x 
2      2   0     
3      3   2 x x 
4      4   1   x 
5      5   0
```

Comment: FYI, you don't need to use `cbind` here. You can do `df$rep = stri_dup('x ", df$num)`

Answer (score 3):

We can also do this using data.table. You mention the data are large, and I suspect many 'nums' will appear in the data multiple times. Therefore, creating each 'rep' string only once and using the fast package data.table will be faster.

```
setDT(dat)[,rep:=paste(rep("x",num),collapse=" "),by=num]
dat

> dat
   sr.no. num rep
1:      1   1   x
2:      2   0    
3:      3   2 x x
4:      4   1   x
5:      5   0
```

Out of interest, and because speed/performance was a concern I ran some benchmarks on a dataset with a million rows.

```
#creating data
set.seed(123)
largedat <- data.frame(sr.no.=1:1e6, num=sample(0:50,1e5, replace=T))
```

These were the (unsurprising) results.

```
Unit: milliseconds
     expr         min          lq        mean      median          uq         max neval cld
   heroka    20.49455    25.44678    34.85443    32.00066    44.51929    57.99193    20 a  
   Krrish   206.14323   272.43439   370.22651   377.10149   467.71401   518.09284    20  b 
 fishtank 12740.56664 12896.42906 13417.82434 13223.84195 13931.15781 14605.41123    20   c
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
> df$rep<-apply(df,1,function(x){ paste(rep("x",x["num"]),collapse=" ")})
> df
  sr.no num rep
1     1   1   x
2     2   0
3     3   2 x x
4     4   1   x
5     5   0
```

`rep(1:2,df$num)` because `df$num` has 5 numbers while `1:2` is just 2 numbers so `rep` has no idea how many times to repeat 1:2.

`rep(1:length(df$num),df$num` is basically `rep(c(1,2,3,4,5),c(1,0,2,1,0))` so it knows to repeat 1 (1 times), 2 (0 times), 3 (2 times), etc...

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer...it works but the data is large so apply will take time. also, thanks for explaining the functionality of rep